# Mapping @ServerEndpoint("/{path:.+}") to any path?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, tomcat7

I can map websocket endpoint to either a set static context or context with a uri variable: `@ServerEndpoint("/{name}")` which will match /anything but not /any/thing. How to map `@ServerEndpoint` so it matches /any/random/uri like `@WebServlet(/*)` would?

Answer (score 1):

I using this solution

**JavaScript part:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.WebSocket) {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/rooms/" + "room number or what ever");
            ws.onopen = function () {
                console.log('Connected');
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                var text = event.data;                    
                console.log(text);
            };
        }
        else {
            // Bad luck. Browser doesn't support it.
        }
    </script>
```

**Java class:**

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@ServerEndpoint(value = "/rooms/{roomnumber}")
public class WebSocketEndPoint implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Map<String, Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Session>());

    public static void sendAll(String text, String roomNumber) {
        synchronized (sessions) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Session> entry : sessions.entrySet()) {
                Session s = entry.getValue();
                if (s.isOpen() && s.getUserProperties().get("roomnumber").equals(roomNumber)) {
                    entry.getValue().getAsyncRemote().sendText(text);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onConnectionOpen(final Session session, @PathParam("roomnumber") final String roomnumber) {
        session.getUserProperties().put("roomnumber", roomnumber);
        sessions.put(String.valueOf(session.getId()), session);
    }


    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        sessions.remove(session.getId());
    }

}
```

If you will have a lot of connections i recommend to use different way to filtrate sessions (different from cycle condition)

Comment: But will it also accept /parking/spot/number? I want a single WebSocketEndpoint class to handle all possible URIs with any level of nesting, like @WebServlet("/*") and req.getRequestURI() would.

Comment: `@ServerEndpoint(value = "/{whatever}")` but it will not accept '-' you or you need to find out how to escape it. But you should use different delimiter to split url like -parking-spot-number

Comment: Is it a correct statement that it's not possible to map @ServerEndpoint to match any URI, like both /one and /one/two/three? I will absolutely have to escape "/" in the path i want to pass like so /one%2Ftwo%2Fthree?

Comment: It will not brings you anything extra. You have my solution as a playground and you can modify it to your needs. This solution can take what ever URI and now its up to you how will you proceed... To be honest I don't see any problems to have more endpoints.